# How to efficiently convert a NSInteger into a NSDecimalNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

So I want to do `NSInteger -> NSDecimalNumber` for decimal computation purpose.

However, the way I am currently doing it, is using NSNumber as an intermediate.

`NSInteger -> NSNumber -> NSDecimalNumber`

```
NSInteger myInteger = 41234312;
NSDecimalNumber *myDecimal = [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:myInteger] decimalValue];
```

Is there a more efficient way to perform this conversion?

Comment: The `decimalValue` returns a `NSDecimal` not `NSDecimalNumber *`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert it to `NSNumber`, You can use :

```
NSDecimalNumber *myDecimal = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInteger:myInteger];
```

`NSDecimal` number is a subclass of `NSNumber` so you can directly use this method.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I can't find the method `numberWithInt` or `decimalNumberWithInt` in NSDecimal's docs https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/index.html

Comment: `NSDecimalNumber` inherits `NSNumber`, and does have `numberWithInt` method (you have to look for it in the base class's documentation). Anyway why don't just try to see if the code works?

Comment: @MichaelHo: as mentioned in comments by other SO users, NSDecimalNumber is a subclass of NSNumber. You can check the documentation

Comment: You guys are right, I didn't notice NSDecimalNumber is a subclass of NSNumber, thanks!!

Comment: `+numberWithInteger:` is expected to return an `NSNumber`, not an `NSDecimalNumber`, regardless of whether it's called from `NSDecimalNumber` or `NSNumber`